How to load an SQLite Binary data dump into an in-memory read-only database instance?
I have an SQLite binary dump of around 10mb. The dumped database contains some catalogue data, which I need to be able to read from really fast from a Ruby application (sub-millisecond). Therefore I was thinking to load the datadump into an in-memory read only instance of SQLite - but - I have a hard time figuring out exactly how?
I have tried something like this, but it does not keep the db in-memory:
require 'sqlite3'
require 'fileutils'

# Path to the binary database dump
binary_dump_path = 'path_to_your_binary_dump.db'

# Create a temporary file
temp_db_path = 'temp_database.db'
FileUtils.copy(binary_dump_path, temp_db_path)

# Open the temporary database
db = SQLite3::Database.new(temp_db_path)

# Optionally, set the database to read-only mode
db.execute('PRAGMA query_only = ON')


You can use the SQLite3::Backup class to copy the source database into memory, and then use that:
# Load source DB
src_db = SQLite3::Database.new('source.db')

# Create destination memory DB 
mem_db = SQLite3::Database.new(':memory:')

# Copy the source DB into the the memory DB
backup = SQLite3::Backup.new(mem_db, 'main', src_db, 'main')
backup.step(-1)
backup.finish

# Do your work on the memory DB
mem_db.execute('SELECT ...') { |row|
  ...
}

